# bitwise operator in PHP

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I've got the following code:

```
print "\n1 & 11\n";
var_dump(1 & 11);

print "\n 2 & 222\n";
var_dump(2 & 222);
```

Why is the first result 1 ? And why is the second result 2?

The [PHP Web site](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) says that `2 & 222` (for example) should give me back a boolean value:

> For example, ***$a & $b == true*** evaluates the equivalency then the bitwise and; while ***($a & $b) == true*** evaluates the bitwise and then the equivalency."

I don't get it, how can `2 & 222` be `2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bits:

1. 01
2. 10
3. 11

The `&` operator returns all bits set to 1 in both numbers. So:

- 1 & 2 -> 01 & 10 -> 00 == 0
- 2 & 3 -> 10 & 11 -> 10 == 2

Answer (score 5):

`&` does a bitwise `AND`. That is, it does an `AND` operation on all the bits of the input.

In binary:

```
2       = 0000000010
222     = 1011011110
2 & 222 = 0000000010 ( = 2)
```

Do not confuse `&` with `&&`. `&` does a `bitwise AND` while `&&` does a `logical AND`.

```
2 && 222 = true
2 &  222 = 2
```

As for `1 & 11`

```
1      = 0001
11     = 1011
1 & 11 = 0001 ( = 1)
```

So, `1 & 11 = 1`

**Further reading:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_and#AND

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate

Answer (score 0):

The single ampersand is the bitwise-and operator.
The quote you've posted is telling you that you should be aware of [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence) when doing bit-operations and comparison. You'd might expect that `$a & $b == true` tests whether certains bits are set in $a, but it's equivalent to

$a & (int)($b==true)

Since you don't mix bit-operations and comparision in `var_dump(1&11);` or `var_dump(2 & 222);` that note shouldn't bother you.
It's a plain bitwise-and as explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

see also:
http://docs.php.net/language.operators.precedence
http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling